# Phaser - having problems referencing with "this' in starter project

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

### The Problem

I am new to Phaser. I am beginning to develop my first real game, and **already** ran into a major roadblock. Specifically, I am getting errors related to ***"this"*** everywhere I turn.

#### My Learning Method

Before I get into the specific errors, I just want to explain my design process. Basically, find a tutorial or code snippet, and grab it and try to use it my game. By learning this way, I think I am running into problems because my coding pattern is not the same as in the tutorial or example I am trying to replicate. Some people are using extending Phaser classes, others are not using classes at all - and I think this may be the root of my problems.

#### 'This' is my pain

Here are a few specific coding errors I am running into in my project:

**1. Creating an on-click handler**
In my game, I will need to run a function when the scene is clicked.

```
  // in my create event

  this.input.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
      console.log(pointer);
  })
```

**Results:**

[image: Input Problem]

**2. Changing the cursor**
I simply want to change the cursor.

```
    // In my create event

    this.input.setDefaultCursor('url(assets/cursors/hand.cur), pointer');
```

**Results:**

[image: Cursor Problem]

> ### At this point I realize something is very wrong in my coding style.

Before I get too much further, I need to figure out what I am doing wrong.

#### Source Code

```
BasicGame.Game = function (game) {

};

var ourGame;

BasicGame.Game.prototype = {

  create: function () {

    // Dont work
    //var allScenes = this.Scene.scenes;

    // Dont work
    this.input.setDefaultCursor('url(assets/cursors/hand.cur), pointer');

    // Dont work
    //this.input.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
      //console.log(pointer);
   // })

    //console.log(allScenes);

    // This DOES work
    this.setupText();

    
  },

  update: function () {
   
  },

  //---------------------------
  // CREATE RELATED FUNCTIONS
  //---------------------------
  setupText: function () {
    this.instructions = this.add.text(
      this.game.width / 4,
      this.game.height - 100,
      'Use Arrow Keys to Move, Press Z to Fire\n' +
      'JOHNNY/clicking does both', {
        font: '20px monospace',
        fill: '#fff',
        align: 'center'
      }
    );
  }



  //---------------------------
  // UPDATE RELATED FUNCTIONS
  //---------------------------
  

  

};
```

Comment: What about the phaser docs? https://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/02-click-on-an-image

Comment: Hard to know exactly what's going wrong without your entire phaser setup (I've run into the same problem, where different tutorials assume different underlying systems). Try adding `console.log(this)` to your `create()` function, and see what properties exist. It looks like the problem is that your Game object isn't picking anything up from the Phaser Game object.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to accept both comments, but dont know how to. I looked in the docs and console.log(this) and found I was not referencing the Phaser class correctly, as sugegsted by both comments. So I got it working by correctly referencing Phaser class. I used the self = this; trick